# How to draw an image as a brush stroke in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Im developing a mobile specific website which allows users to draw complex patterns and shapes to their liking. I discovered that canvas is a good way to do this. I understand that canvas has a `drawimage` function that allows for this. But is it possible to do this as in a brush stroke format, where instead of the basic 1px stroke default, you use an actual image?

These images that the users can draw with are indeed graphic `png` images. I found a tutorial online that shows this however its quite old and very complex and heavy in terms of its code structure, here is a link [click here](https://dzone.com/articles/sketching-html5-canvas-and). There is a good chance I will be developing this website with webflow. Would this be possible with webflow? and, furthermore, smartphone devices? Thanks Guys

[Click here to see an image of my prototype to get a better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVljm.png)

Comment: Are you talking about a free drawing component? If so, do you have the basics with this 1px stroke? Ps: even though the link is old, the basics are still the same and the way they used back then sounds like a good way, even nowadays.

Comment: Hey! Ya its a free drawing component. I figured out how to do it actually now with images I found a codepen that was very helpful and made sense https://codepen.io/kangax/pen/bhiKl. What I have to do now is figure out how to do this for mobile using touchevents.